# The excel macro generates a huge file in csv format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 9Mb workbook of 4 worksheets. One of the worksheets was exported to csv format using a macro. My problem is that it will be 93Mb in size. When I open and save it, it will be 1Mb.

What is the error, what can I do, here is the macro:

```
Sub cssexport1()
    
    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo err
    
    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSV" & ".csv"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Munka3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    With tempWB
    .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    .Close
    End With
err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Any strange warning when you save the file? try without `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Also, you save the file with macro, then its 93 mb and if you manually open that 93 mb file and then just save it again as csv, it becomes 1 Mb? Try using the macro recorder and see if the fileformat matches.

Comment: if I save it myself, I saved the worksheet differently, it will be 1Mb. If the macro does it, it's 93Mb. After I open the csv file created by the macro and do a save (Ctr+s), it goes down to 1Mb.

Comment: This sounds really strange. What happens if you increase your code adding a second saving? After closing the 93 mb workbook, open it again and save it. Something like `Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(myCSVFileName)` and then `tempWB.Save`. Does it keep being 93 Mb or does it becomes 1 Mb? Also, is the original file 93 mb???? Any Pivot Table on the sheet you are exporting as CSV?

Comment: The SetTempVBA (A8which you suggested) I don't know where to put in the code. One interesting thing: it finishes generating very quickly, but it takes at least 30s to go up to OneDrive. Because the original file is in Sharpoint folder and that's where the csv goes back to.
I also made another workbook with these 3959 lines and 3 worksheets with a few lines. Here the uploaded macro csv will be 1Mb. It will be done in no time.

Comment: xlsx is a zipped/compressed file format, so it's not surprising the exported CSV would be larger than the source file.

Comment: I found the error. I deleted everything from the Excel worksheet and the worksheet I wanted to save: it was completely blank. The file size was still 2Mb. I deleted the worksheet, created another with the same content. In a matter of moments, the csv file was quickly created, which was 1Mb in size. It must have been some Excel bug...